# Why does HDFS serialize using protocol buffers, not Java serialization APIs?

Tags: java, hadoop, serialization, hdfs, protocol-buffers

Why does HDFS use a protocol buffer instead of the Java serialization API?

What if I want to send an object from a data node to another data node via Java serialization?

I've tried a couple of things and I get the following error:
java.io.WriteAbortedException: writing aborted; java.io.NotSerializableException: java.lang.Thread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because formats with external schema definition like Protocol Buffers are more space efficient then build-in Java serialization which produces a very verbose file.

HDFS can use different format to store the data. Formats that provide best space efficiency while not being overly CPU intensive are generally preferred. Some format are designed for a specific goal which helps with data processing:

- [Avro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Avro) which is row oriented
- [Parquet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Parquet) which is column oriented

`java.io.NotSerializableException: java.lang.Thread` exception shows that you are attempting to serialize [`Thread`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) which is not implementing `Serializable`